# why do i getting boost.URL linking error?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, build, boost-asio

This is my project :
https://github.com/Naseefabu/HFTBOT/blob/master/src/main.cpp

When i try to build it,
Error :
https://gist.github.com/Naseefabu/5a114956f39b6c853916bcaf66f939e4

Is it because that i included `boost/url/src.hpp` in both httpClient.cpp and httpClient.hpp ??

What's the solution here ?

please help and advance thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the URL library](https://github.com/CPPAlliance/url/tree/3b6e2afafcd8733ec453c2595e1d434913eed335#header-only):

> To use as header-only; that is, to eliminate the requirement to link a program to a static or dynamic Boost.URL library, simply place the following line *in exactly **one** new or existing **source** file* in your project.
>
> ```
> #include <boost/url/src.hpp>
> ```

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

You include that header file in one of your own header files, which is included in *both* your source files.

As the documentation says, it should be included in only *one* source file (my recommendation is that you do it in a separate source file, for that specific purpose).

Comment: @dopller Leave everything as it is right now, with the only change that `httpClient.hpp` should *not* have `#include "boost/url/src.hpp"`. Then create a new source file which *only* have `#include "boost/url/src.hpp"` in it. Build with the new source file.